# how to import python code into views.py file in django

Tags: python, django, import

I am new to django and I am trying to link a response from a form submission to a couple python methods I wrote in a different file which will use the user input as parameters. 
I am wondering how I can import those methods and print their results.

My python file is named `Crunch.py` and is located in the same directory as `views.py` I have tried: `from Crunch import *` 
but it isn't working. I would like to know if I need to move the file elsewhere or what I need to write to import all the methods from Crunch.

Comment: do you get errors? what is not working? you should post some code...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following

```
from <app name>.Crunch import *
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also do

```
from .Crunch import *
```