# How can I import my own script into models.py in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have created a small script for comparing how similar two images are. This is contained in a file called `compare_image.py`, which contains just one function, `compare`. This file is in the app directory. I am trying to import it from the `models.py` file using the line `import compare_image`, but attempting this results in the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compare_image'`.

The simplified directory structure looks like this:

```
myproject
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── compare_image.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

`myapp` is the only app in the project. Apart from this, the webapp functions fine.

I have tried deleting and re`touch`ing the `__init__.py` file to no avail. I can import `compare_image` fine from a python shell in the `myapp` directory. The only imports in `compare_image.py` are to PIL or standard libraries, so I don't think circular imports are the culprit.

One solution would be to just put the code in `models.py`, but I don't want to clutter this file.

I thought since this error seems so basic there might be some standard mechanism for user-written scripts in Django, but I can't find any mention of this online.

I would be happy to provide more details about the project if it will make things clearer. Thanks in advance for any help (this error is driving me crazy!)

Comment: Can you post the contents of compare_image.py?

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169133/how-to-import-python-code-into-views-py-file-in-django

Comment: Thanks @cslotty, yes this is effectively the exact same problem. I thought I had tried that solution, but maybe I fixed something else in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing an absolute import where you need a relative one. Can you try:

```
from .compare_image import compare
```

from a python file in the same folder as `compare_image.py`?

Comment: Wow, I thought I had tried every combination and style of import but this really solved it! Can you shed any light on why this is necessary, when I can import the package as normal from a simple script in the same directory?

Comment: When you import a module, that module will be searched in the search path (see `import sys; sys.path`). If you are running a simple script, search path will have file's directory so you can import any module in the same directory. When you are using Django, Python search path will not include your directory (you can set `PYTHONPATH` but this is not recommended) so you would need to use relative imports.